# How do the two sides of the Schrodinger equation match?

Tags: operator-theory, physics

This is the form of the Schrodinger equation given by Wikipedia.

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}|\Psi(t)\rangle=\hat{H}|\Psi(t)\rangle$$

My question is a simple one, but difficult for me to understand the answer to. To what space does each side of the equation belong? The left hand side is a constant scalar factor times the time derivative of a column vector, so it belongs to the same space as the vector. The right hand side is the Hamiltonian operator applied to a column vector, which yields energy, a scalar. I must be misunderstanding one of these two expressions since, in my interpretation, they belong to different spaces and are completely incomparable.

Comment: Hamiltonian is an operator here, and maps a vector to another vector. Like a matrix. To get a scalar out of it you can take an inner product. Notationwise that would add a bra to the ket.

Comment: What's confusing then, is the definitions I see for the potential and kinetic energies are scalars. I think I'm understanding correctly now that what this is saying is not that the operator is the sum of the potential and kinetic energies, but that bra-operator-ket is the sum of the energies. This is unclear in multiple places on Wikipedia to a relative layperson. Put it in an answer, show the notation, and help me understand the significance / meaning of values in the range of the Hamiltonian operator, if possible.

Comment: With $H  = - \sum_j \partial_{x_j}^2$ (the laplacian operator) the equation is $ih \partial_t \Psi(x,t) = - \sum_j \partial_{x_j}^2 \Psi(x,t)$ where $\Psi(x,t)$ is a complex number, $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ represents the density of probability/energy. A quantum system is defined by its $H$ operator which must be hermitian with real eigenvalues on an Hilbert space for the energy levels to make sense. For this reason when $H$ starts being time dependent quantum physics become a huge mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\Psi\rangle$ is not a vector in the usual sense. It is a vector **if viewed as a solution in the vector space of all solutions**, or in physicists' words, **a quantum state**.

For an anology, we can say all polynomials $\mathbb R[x]$ over $\mathbb R$ is a vector space, with basis $1,x,x^2,\cdots$. Then any polynomial $p(x)$ is a **vector** in the sense you view it as an element in $\mathbb R[x]$. On the other hand, you can still put it into an equation (assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}$)
$$\frac{dp}{dx}=2x$$
in which case $p(x)$ is just a **real variable depending on another real variable $x$**.

So in the Schrodinger's equation, instead of thinking of $|\Psi\rangle$ as a vector, you should think of it as **a complex variable depending on time and the space coordinates**, so both sides are simply complex variables.

p.s. even so the RHS is not the energy.

---

**Reply to the comment** (too long to put in the comment):

I am not saying it is not a vector. I am saying it is simultaneously a vector and a complex variable. Let me start from the beginning.

**WHAT IS THIS "VECTOR" WE ARE TALKING ABOUT**

First, when you mention vector, you need to be sure of what vector space you are referring to. If you have seen some examples of solving Schrodinger's equation, say, the infinite well problem, you'll know by separating the space and time variables $\Psi(x,y,z,t)=\Phi(x,y,z)\psi(t)$one can derive from the time-dependent equation a time-independent one:
$$\hat H\Phi=E\Phi$$
where $E$ is a constant. Usually the equation has a system of time-independent solutions $\Phi_n(r)$ ($r=(x,y,z)$), called the **eigenfunctions** (also eigenvectors, but I'd like to avoid the word "vector" for now), which satisfy
$$\hat H\Phi_n=E_n\Phi_n$$
where $E_n$ are called the **eigenvalues**. All other solutions has the form
$$\Psi(r,t)=\sum_n c_ne^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\Phi_n(r)$$
To make a solution normalizable, one must impose the condition
$$\int_{\rm all\ space}\bar\Psi\Psi dV<\infty\iff\sum_n|c_n|<\infty$$

Now comes the crucial part: **what is the vector space we keep talking about? It is the vector space of all solutions!** In the case above, it is

$$S=\left\{\sum_n c_ne^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\Phi_n(r):\ \sum_n|c_n|<\infty\right\}$$

One can verify that this is a vector space, and has an inner product
$$<f,g>=\int(\bar fg)dV$$
on it, under which $e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\Phi_n$ is a system of orthogonal basis of $S$.

**SUMMARY:**

So there's no problem saying that $\Psi$ is a vector, as long as you see it as one. But you have to distinguish between the two explanations below:

(1) $\Psi(r,t)$ as a function, assumes value in a vector space ($\mathbb C^n$ or $\mathbb C^\infty$) over $\mathbb{C}$.

(2) $\Psi(r,t)$ assumes value in $\mathbb C$, and as a function itself (i.e. a mapping, a rule of correspondence), belongs to a set of functions, which constitute a vector space.

I guess you were thinking (1), but I am trying to explain (2) to you.

I'd like to say more but too tired now. I suggest reading some textbooks instead of Wikipedia:

**SUGGESTED READING MATERIALS**

[1] Sect. 1.2-1.5 *Mathematical Concepts of Quantum Mechanics* by Stephen J. Gustafson and Israel Michael Sigal

[2] Sect. 8.1-8.2 *Quantum Mechanics* by Franz Schwabl

p.s. I am not sure whether there's a name for $\hat H\Psi$.

Comment: A solution in a vector space is still a vector. What you're saying contradicts Jyrki Lahtonen's comment on my question "Hamiltonian is an operator here, and maps a vector to another vector." And if the right hand side is not the energy, what is it?

Comment: I replied in the answer because there was too much to add :)

Comment: It is not a complex number, but a complex-valued function (well, at least in the simplest case). If it were a complex number, its derivative would be identically zero.

Comment: @celtschk You didn't read it through. I said it was a complex number depending on space coordinates ang time, which is exactly a complex-valued function. The reason I didn't say "complex-valued function" at first is that I needed to stress the function itself is a vector, and I didn't want the word "function" to cause confusion (apparently I caused confusion anyway, but please read it through).

Comment: @trisct: As written, that doesn't make sense. You could however replace “complex number” by “complex value”.

Comment: @celtschk Okay. Maybe I it is a language thing. In my native language "complex number"="complex value". I changed "complex number" to "complex variable" if "number" implies constant for native English speakers.

Comment: Well this clarifies the notation a bit, it's just very confusing to me that you refer to a vector as a function - but I guess the point is it's infinite dimensional rather than finite dimensional so you can view the vector as a scalar function. It's still a vector object though.

Comment: Confusing indeed. When I first knew that  physicists call them vectors I had the same questions you do. And it had been years before I finally understood it. I do recommend reading something more (even if you don't fully understand it yet) and then come back to the equation, rather than just getting stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Psi$ is an eigenvector of $H$ then $H\Psi = E\Psi$, a vector.
If $\Psi$ is not an eigenvector of $H$ then $H\Psi$ is a vector but not a constant multiple of $\Psi$.

Comment: Is E an operator or a scalar constant?

Comment: @VoidStar A scalar. Do you have the math for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices and differential operators? The latter is similar to wave propagation in cavities and  waveguides (including dielectric).

Comment: Yes, I've very comfortable with eigenvalues and eigenvectors. All of my math comes from an electrical engineering background with significant RF experience so linear systems are no problem; I get confused by notation in pure physics and math texts. Interested where you're going with this.

Comment: @VoidStar The Wikipedia articles are not a good place to start. If you google [Quantum Mechanics for Electrical Engineers](https://www.google.ca/search?q=quantum+mechanics+for+electrical+engineers), there is a book with that title (I've only read the blurb) and various discussions. For example, the math of a 1D QM finite potential well is similar to a 2D dielectric waveguide.

Comment: That looks like a good book suggestion. Although, contrary to your advice, I find a Wikipedia binge gives me some context to know what I'm looking for before I spend money on books or academic papers (in addition to my monthly Wikipedia donation)

Comment: I have accepted the answer @trisct gave because there is more useful detail which gives additional context for me. I think your answer more succinctly addresses the basic confusion though and I appreciate your effort.